# Why android.os.IServiceManager in Android not resolving

Tags: android, import, resolve

I am coding for DialerDemo, But import android.os.IServiceManager;import android.os.ServiceManagerNative; import android.telephony.IPhone;  are not resolving

```
CODE:
package com.umesh.umeshfilereadwritedemo1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.DeadObjectException;
import android.os.IServiceManager;
import android.os.ServiceManagerNative;
import android.telephony.IPhone;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DialerDemo extends Activity

 {

    ...
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all internal classes of the SDK, and are not available publicly.

You cannot build source.android.com applications on their own. They can only be built as part of a firmware image. Please follow the [instructions](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) to build the entire firmware. While you can use [Eclipse](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) to edit the firmware source, you will still use `make` to build the firmware.